# Printing an HTML form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, printing

I am having an HTML form, and I need to print(HardCopy) particular area..

The problem is I am unable to get the form Text1 and Text2 values on the. Since I need that HTML form to be filled with some value, while clicking *print it* should print as hardcopy.

#### My Code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#print").click(function(){
                   alert($('#click').html());
                   // It shows only form elements; I need a form typed element too. How?
                   window.print();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="click">
            Text1: <input id="l" type="text" />
            Text2: <input id="m" type="text"/>
            <input id="print" type="button" value="Print-Me"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want the text that is typed in the text1 and text2 input fields. You can do so with the `.val()` function, like this:

```
$("#print").click(function(){
    alert($('#l').val() + '\n' + $('#m').val());
    window.print();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Print Element Plugin](http://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/raw/master/jQuery.printElement/jquery.printElement.min.js) in the jQuery library:

```
$("#print").click(function(){
    printElem({ printMode: 'popup' });
});
function printElem(options){
    $('#click').printElement(options);
}
```

Comment: Well, seems you found the answer on your own. :)