# Capturing the values of form elements for printing

Tags: jquery, printing

I'm fairly competent at using JQuery, and can usually get most things to work with a bit of messing around. I tried googling this problem but either I'm searching the wrong terms, or there's no published solution.

When preparing the print.css file for an order form page, I was asked if I could remove the text INPUTS and just print out their values, likewise a SELECT menu containing an address.

When researching I did come across the .val() method - now known as .fieldValue() - and the .serializeArray() so I think I know how I could extract the value, just not how to print it in place of the form element.

Just to be clear:
The SELECT menu for instance, shows the first line of the default delivery address. 
For the printout, I'd like it to actually display the whole address, across several lines, and no SELECT menu.

I have this solution below working, which allows me to capture the values, but I don't know how to insert them in place of the form elements:
[Printing an HTML form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457254/printing-html-form-jquery?rq=1)

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT
The captured values should only be inserted in the printout, not replace the form elements in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic solution as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mBSS/15/

Basically: when something happens (like a button is clicked), loop over the corresponding elements and use the `.replaceWith()` jQuery function to replace them with their value... which you get with `.val()`. As you can see this works fine with `<select>` as well as `<input>` elements.

You can of course create a more complex HTML element to replace the inputs with, eg `"<p>" + val + "</p>"`.

Note that this will completely remove the form input fields until the page is reloaded. This might not matter at all (if you for example open the print page in a new tab) or it might break the design of your site... Personally I prefer to use a print CSS sheet to style the printed pages, for example removing the border on input boxes. But this might not work well if you need to extract the value of a selected option in a `<select>` element.

If you want to keep the page intact, I would recommend that you embed some hidden elements to hold the text for printing, and copy the input forms' values to them when clicking the print button... then in your print CSS you hide all inputs and instead display the backing elements (for example `<p>` or `<span>`).

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks for taking the time to help. I am using some print.css as well to format the page correctly btw. I'm going to use that to remove the borders/shadow on the text inputs, but this is helpful for outputting the address from the select menu. I have added window.print(); to the end of the function you wrote, but as you said, the function is removing the inputs/selects from the page. Clicking the PRINT button opens the browser print dialogue window, not another tab, so once the user has printed the document, they return to the original page which now looks messed up.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another paragraph with an approach for this type of problem. Let me know if it helps, or if you need more info.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. I gave it a go but no success yet:
[http://jsfiddle.net/gyUDM/]

Comment: I didn't intend that you should use `<input type="hidden" />` but rader normal HTML elements that are hidden *with CSS* and displayed *with CSS* when you print.